# Is FIS (Fidelity National Information Systems) a client of CENTRL?

Tags: banking, security, customer-service, phishing

The company CENTRL [lists FIS](https://www.oncentrl.com/partners/)* as a client on their website. **Can anyone verify this, or show me how to verify it?**

Susquehanna [mentions CENTRL](https://sgep.com/company/centrl/) on their site as someone they have backed.

*FIS site: [https://www.fisglobal.com](https://fisglobal.com)

I'm asking for personal anti-phishing reasons: I sent an email to FIS global, and shortly got a (not totally expected) email back from CENTRL. They want my phone number and for me to click some links. I've verified to my satisfaction that the above email came from CENTRL and is normal for them. Now I'm just trying to verify that CENTRL itself isn't obviously untrustworthy.
I tried calling FIS about it but they couldn't figure it out (I think because that verification isn't part of their job, not because the answer is complex).

**Details on the email I received**

- sender address: do-not-reply@oncentrl.com
- sender name: FIS Internal via CENTRL
- subject: Request logged successfully
- text: included a ticket number and a link to web.oncentrl.com

Comment: What's the actual address used by CENTRL?  Otherwise, we can't fully answer your question.

Comment: Good question @RonJohn, I will add that detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether they are or not, I don't blame you for being suspicious about the questions.

Contact FIS, tell them what you've told us, tell them that you're uncomfortable with the unexpected third-party contact, and ask them if this is a legitimate part of their process and why CENTRL didn't get the information from them. If it's a scam, they will certainly tell you and appreciate the heads-up. If it isn't, I'd bet you are far from the first to ask; be proud that you're paying attention rather than embarrassed to ask.

Comment: (1/2) Thanks! I tried calling them but I did not do what you said; I didn't really have a plan. I will try what you said.

Comment: (2/2) In my original attempt, I just explained the email and asked whether they were a CENTRL client. They said they weren't sure. But I think maybe I called the wrong FIS phone number, because their decision tree basically wanted me to be a bank. The problem I'm having is that FIS is pretty much B2B so I can't find a good number for an individual to call. The email from CENTRL, if legitimate, is a response to a one-off email that I sent to one of their corporate email addresses regarding my personal ChexSystems account. I'll try calling Chex customer support also.

Comment: Thanks @Keshlam. I called ChexSystems customer service to ask whether that message was legitimate. They said it was. They also said that any future correspondence about my original issue should be done by mail, which seems a little contradictory. So I'm about 80% sure that it's okay. I went ahead and clicked the link and gave my phone number. Let's hope I didn't just sign away my identity to some clever hackers!!

Comment: Phone number is relatively easy to look up, so I don't think you've given away much if anything that hackers would find useful. At worst you might find yourself targeted for more robocalls -- not that "more" is very possible these days. <grin/>

Answer (score 1):

https://www.oncentrl.com/ exists.  You can determine that by just going to it.

But maybe it's a scam site.  If so, they did a very thorough job of it.  And it was registered [almost four years ago](https://www.whois.com/whois/onecentrl.com), not last month.

My only question would be why FIS used CENTRL to validate you.  And the answer is [DD360](https://www.oncentrl.com/due-diligence/):

> DD360 is the most advanced and comprehensive software platform for automating the due diligence process for investors, allocators and consultants.

Comment: Thanks @RonJohn, I called ChexSystems and they said it was legitimate (although they didn't inspire 100% confidence). I clicked the link, hope it turns out okay!

Comment: Thanks again @RonJohn, I marked the other one as the answer but this also helped me.